# PhD in Mathematical Finance

Tags: phd, mathematics, finance

I applied to a PhD program in Applied Mathematics, but was accepted to the PhD program in Mathematical Finance instead. It seems that one professor found my background in control theory and signal processing attractive.

The school I was accepted to is great, I'd be getting a decent amount of funding and my potential advisor seems to be a nice guy.
However, I'm concerned about having the word "finance" in my degree. My fear is that it could pigeonhole me to academic positions in business schools after graduation (where most of the former students of my potential advisors have gone). My original goal was to become a professor in a math/engineering department or a researcher in a tech company after my PhD, and I doubt that a PhD in Mathematical Finance would help me to get that.

Does anybody knows where do people with PhDs in Mathematical Finance end up going?

Comment: Wherever they want. People are unlikely to turn you down for a job based solely on your degree title. If most of your PhD work is on control theory and signal processing, then your publications, CV and cover letter when applying for your desired jobs will make it clear that you're a good candidate.